# How would I search for topics about deleted functions in C++ 11?

Tags: support, search

I've tried

```
[c++11] = delete

[c++11] "= delete"

[c++11] "=delete"
```

but I get topics about 'delete', '=', and others.

Comment: if you want my advice, use a proper search engine and use `site:stackoverflow.com`. It's not as good at finding by tags, but [it's at least slightly better](https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=c%2B%2B11+%3D+delete+site%3Astackoverflow.com) than SO's built-in search (which is awful at finding anything containing anything that isn't a "normal" letter, in case you haven't noticed)

Comment: Try deleted functions instead of = delete

Comment: [`[c++11] code:"=delete"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B11%5D+code%3A%22%3Ddelete%22&searchOn=3)?

Comment: @AndrewT. Yeah, that makes sense.  If the code snippet is real small, I personally tend to put it in-line `A() = delete;` in answer text but not in a code section (and obvious I do it in comments).  Regardless, more answers will have syntax type queries in `[code]` sections (oops, I did it again).

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, I'd suggest avoiding the SO search feature; use your favorite search engine, and filter by the site with `site:stackoverflow.com`. I search for duplicate targets a lot, and have generally had more success with a search engine.

More importantly, don't search for *syntax*, such as `=delete`. As you've observed, you'll get a lot of hits for the `delete` operator, as well as the assignment operator `=`. Instead, search for the *name* of the feature, in this case, "deleted functions".

Also, don't search for a specific language revision, such as C++11, even though that's the revision the feature was added in. Simply search for C++ and you'll get the hits for C++11 as well.

Running a search for [site:stackoverflow.com c++ deleted functions](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+c%2B%2B+deleted+functions&t=ffab&ia=web) on DDG yields a number of useful hits (I've listed the first 5)

- [error: use of deleted function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966698)
- [error: use of deleted function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47704900)
- [Meaning of = delete after function declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513881)
- [attempting to reference a deleted function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603735)
- [C++ error : non deleted function cannot override a deleted function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66987537)

4 of these are actually debugging questions (which are still useful to read), but the 3rd result is a canonical that explains the feature quite well, both for regular functions, as well as the more common context of special member functions.

Comment: If what you say is true, SO search engine should just do what you recommended.  i guess they have to keep the employees busy refining their own algorithms ;-)

Comment: The only reason I changed the filter from [c++] to [c++11] was to reduce the HUGE superset of delete, =, etc.  It did reduce it, but not to a useful enough level hence the reason for the question.

Comment: @franji1 Actually, there's a bunch of stuff you can do with SO search that is not really possible with a search engine. Click on the "Advanced search tips" when searching, and you'll see the options. You can filter by score, date of posting, and a number of other things. So in some cases, SO search *is* preferable, just not in the case that you've mentioned in this question.